# How to save console output with timeout command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, shell

I want to be able to save console output of a php script when I am using timeout. The following command runs the script but does not create the *xyz.out* file

```
timeout -k 10s 3h nohup php foobar.php > xyz.out
```

I think my syntax is wrong. Can someone show me the correct syntax.

Comment: You're redirecting the output of Timeout, not the command Timeout is running.  Perhaps try something like `timeout -k 10s 3h "nohup php foobar.php > xyz.out"` so that the pipe is included as part of the command Timeout is to run (note, I have not tested this, it's just an educated guess ;) ).

Comment: Techie007, you are probably right but quotes do not work. I get error timeout:falied to run command "php foobar.php >xyz.out" : no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution consists in writing a file named `command.sh` with the following content:

```bash
nohup php foobar.php > xyz.out
```

and then run the command

```bash
timeout -k 10s 3h bash command.sh
```